# Database queries with ModelForm Model(Multiple) Choice fields in Django

Tags: python, ajax, django, modelform

I have a form with some Model(Multiple)Choice fields that have so many options that I would like to trim down the available options based on user responses on the front-end, and then populate the select options through AJAX.

I am a little confused as to when Django will query the database in this case, and what are considered the best practices for Django ModelChoice fields that are populated with AJAX data.

Originally, I had been doing things like this:

```
contact = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=aRelatedModel.objects.all())
```

or a restricted queryset:

```
contact = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=aRelatedModel.objects.filter(somefield = someValue))
```

So, my question is, when does the DB get queried for ModelChoice options?

The confusion stems from another form I did, where I had a ModelChoiceField with the ability to add new options dynamically.  In that case, unless I instantiated the ModelChoiceField *after* saving the new option, I would get an error.  This makes me feel like the database is queried on form instantiation.  But, given the lazy nature of Django querysets, it seems like it would also make sense that the DB is not queried until you iterate over said list (ie, when printing the form options).

So, in this kind of case is there a way to avoid potentially needless DB queries?  What is the best practice for ModelChoiceFields that will be populated with AJAX data?

I've seen mentions of:

```
contact = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=aRelatedModel.objects.none())
```

...but never any explicit explanation on why to use this.

**Edit:**

In that case, I had a form with

```
field = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = relatedModel.objects.all())
```

Subsequently in the view, I naively did:
`myForm = modelForm(request.POST)`.  This produced an error if I instantiated the form *before* first saving the dynamically added field.  After adding the field, and then calling modelForm(request.POST) I no longer had an "invalid choice" error - presumably because the dynamically added field was now included in the modelForm queryset.

I am not sure how that is relevant to the question, however.  The question is when a modelForm's queryset is populated with data from the DB.

Comment: What error did you get when you did it the other way

Comment: @DanielRoseman Invalid choice.

Comment: That's not really much help without knowing exactly what you were doing.